# Mysql query on date function

Tags: php, mysql

I have table "movie" which consists of a field "date of release"
how do I query that, which movie hit's the theatre every friday?

Comment: Improve your question by showing what you have tried

Comment: you should use mysql's `DATE_FORMAT()` function... take look at mysql date and time functions.. refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: We have no idea what your database looks like. We have no idea what you actually want. Do you want every friday for a full year or just the current weeks friday? You're not clear enough.

Comment: I want every friday not only for current week and my database is phpmyadmin.

Comment: I want to display on my UI that which movie releases every friday.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$r = false;
$movie = false;

$r = query("SELECT id FROM movie WHERE dateOfRelease='friday'");

$movieInfo = query("SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id='{$r[\'id\']}'");
```

Made some assumptions because your question has very little information, hopefully this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can find out this week's friday like this:

```
$datefriday=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next friday'));
```

Assuming you have a `date()` type field in your database, you can use a query like:

```
SELECT column1,column2,column3,column4 from movie where date_of_release = $datefriday
```

I have no idea if you use mysqli, pdo or even mysql. So I cant let the query run in php for you. The query has to look like this though. If you want the friday of the week after that, you can use:

```
$date_next_friday=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefriday.'+ 7 days'));
```

This should help you.